# stop listview.builder from scrolling

Tags: image, listview, flutter, stack

I have an array of image URLs. I need to show them in a listview.builder that isn't scrolling down. I want it to show them as a stack. 
[image: Like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget for this purpose. You can pass your list of images to stacks `children` property.

Example:

```
class _StackImagesState extends State<StackImages> {

  List<String> _urls = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _urls = [
      "https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/royalty-free-stock-eyelash-clipart-glitter-glitter-eyelash-transparent-background-11562955805upbu10lfl4.png",
      "https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/8-82184_banner-free-stock-apple-transparent-background-image-apple.png"
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children:_urls.map((String url) => Image.network(url)).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The image URLs are in an array, How should I pass it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.network(url:arr[0]),
        Image.network(url:arr[1]),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

you could lay image one by one from  array